# MacOS virtual output device

Tags: audio, virtualization, macos

On my Macbook Pro I had an accident after which all audio output devices (both speakers and minijack) stopped working.

They actually are not recognized by macbook so there is no possibility to configure it via sound settings.

Guys from repair service tried to fix it but they couldn't. 
So I started using wireless speakers or headphones.

My question originated after I tried to open video without any wireless output device. It couldn't be played actually.

So I have an idea. What if I can virtually mock my sound output device. 
I found a lot of recording programs, but I don't need to record audio. I only need to have virtual audio output device which will catch audio signal and do nothing with it.

Is there any software I can use?

Answer (score 0):

As a direct answer to your question I don't know of any software solution that will provide a 'known output' without actually having one to send to.

You could possibly try Soundflower. I haven't used it in a long time, but it has been recently maintained by 'mattingalls' after several years of uncertain future, first being abandoned by Cycling'74, the original authors, then again by Rogue Amoeba, who had taken over its upkeep. See https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower/releases for the current status.

Alternatively, you could add a physical USB soundcard. The cheapest ones are about $£€ 1 & will provide a recognisable source for input/output.

They should require no drivers for Mac & just work out of the box.

This is a current listing from [eBay UK](https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_sacat=0&_nkw=usb%20soundcard&_sop=15), sorted by cheapest. Any of these should do the task, however cheap & nasty they really are - the technology to do simple analog-digital i/o to USB is well-established.
I have a slightly more expensive one - a whole £7 ;)  that I use to output 5.1 as discrete 6-channel analog from my old Mac Pro '08.

Comment: Good suggestion about usb soundcard. But it's almost similar to my solution with wireless garniture because I need to use something with minijack everytime. 
But actually I can take separate minijack and use it with such soundcard. Thank you for the response!